# PowerMockEasyMock: Failed to transform class with name

Tags: unit-testing, junit4, powermock, easymock, powermockito

I am using PowerMockEasyMock 1.5.5 along with EasyMock 3.2. I wanted to mock a new object created within a method that requires @PrepareForTest. But whenever I do this, I get this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name 
com.amazon.awsaccounts.notificationlistenerservice.proxies.MyClassTest. Reason: sorry, cannot edit NEW followed by no DUP
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:177)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:138)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: sorry, cannot edit NEW followed by no DUP
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.canReplace(NewExpr.java:150)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:170)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:427)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:198)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1224)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:74)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:243)
    ... 28 more
```

I have even tried to do this with PowerMockMockito 1.6.x but still got the same problem. I have read the posts in Stackoverflow but non got me the solution. I researched online about this and understood that there is a problem with older version of Javassist that is a dependency in PowerMockMockito as well as PowerMockEasyMock. I added Javassist 3.20.x in my version set but still getting the same error. Anybody has an idea as to what would be the correct configuration?

Comment: You have a problem with your code. Doesn't it occur to you to include that code in your question?! If you would be a newbie, I would recommend you to read [mcve] again. But you could be around long enough to know that ;-) ... and beyond that: the sane, better approach (if possible) is always to **not** use PowerMock (but instead use **dependency injection** to enable you to provide a mocked object to your *code under test*. The simple equation "using PowerMock equals pain" isn't always true; but far too often.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one version of Javassist in class path? Which build tool do you use?